# RStudio: Using filter, group_by, and summarise as input for ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, group-by, summarize

I'm trying to create a column chart showing the number of rides by gender, for only non-members. It would have two columns: one showing total number of rides for non-member males, and one showing total number of rides for non-member females.

This code works fine, but it includes both members and non-members:

```
FullData %>% 
  group_by(CustomerType, Gender) %>% 
  summarise(number_of_rides = n()) %>% 
  arrange(CustomerType, Gender)  %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Gender, y = number_of_rides, fill = CustomerType)) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge")
```

Below is my latest attempt at creating the chart to only show non-members, but it doesn't work - the plot pane sets up with just axis labels of `Gender` and `number_of_rides`, the rest is a gray empty plot area where the columns should be.
Plus, I get this message: `summarise()` has grouped output by 'CustomerType'. You can override using the `.groups` argument.

```
FullData %>% 
  dplyr::filter(CustomerType == 'non-member') %>%   
  group_by(CustomerType, Gender) %>% 
  summarise(number_of_rides = n()) %>% 
  arrange(CustomerType, Gender)  %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Gender, y = number_of_rides, fill = CustomerType)) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge")
```

Comment: the message is just a warning message. You can change by adding `.groups = "drop"` in `summarise`

Comment: or you can add a line `ungroup() %>%` after the `summarise`. The issue arises here because you grouped across two variables (ie separate groups for each combination of CustomerType and Gender), but the default behavior of `summarise` is to drop only the most-recently created level of grouping, in this case `Gender`, but keep the others. Updated in mid-2020 with dplyr 1.0 to have more options. https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/summarise.html

Comment: What do you mean by doesn't work? That message is unrelated and can be ignored. Do you get any other warning/error message ? It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: Updated post to clarify issue is an empty plot area with no columns.